# Entity Framework is messing up Calls and pages loading extremely slow

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I have a code first asp.net mvc5 project which is taking 30+ seconds to load a page with just a few rows of data, both on local and production systems, and it's not just for the first time (the first time is actually around 10 seconds longer but I understand why). I disabled debugging, and did a few other tricks that I could find online but the best I could do is shorten that time to about 25 seconds.

The thing is, for one of the page for instance, I am getting a table from the database but when i'm checking to see what the database actually does, it's querying each row independently in stead of getting the entire table.

I am accessing the context trough generic interfaces. Here are the methods that does the actual call.

```
        public async Task<IQueryable<TEntity>> Load<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
    {
        var set = await Task.FromResult(Set<TEntity>());

        return set;
    }

    public async Task Create<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : class
    {
        if (Entry(entity).State == EntityState.Detached)
            Set<TEntity>().Add(entity);
        await this.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    public async Task Update<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : class
    {
        if (Entry(entity).State == EntityState.Detached)
            Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
        await this.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    public async Task Delete<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : class
    {
        if (Entry(entity).State == EntityState.Detached)
            Set<TEntity>().Remove(entity);
        await this.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    public async Task<IQueryable<TEntity>> Query<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
    {
        return await Task.FromResult(Set<TEntity>().AsNoTracking()); // detach results from context
    }
```

for the page I was talking about I am using the Load method. Also, these methods are located in the context class. Another thing that might help: I am building a multi layered application. I have my domain layer where I have my context. Generic interfaces to access that context, the store calls the interface and converts everything to DTO's, the manager inherits the store and does some more work on the data if it's needed (right now i'm only generating id's and that sort of stuff), On the managers I've built another set of interfaces that are being called by the Application Services layer, which is being called in turn by the MVC layer (through interfaces again). Everything is injected with a .InstancePerLifetimeScope() by Autofac.

here is the example for this one class:

The context: (is code-first from existing database)

```
  public partial class PurchasingContext : DbContext, IWritePurchasingEntities
{
    public PurchasingContext()
        : base("name=PurchasingContext")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<AttachedFile> AttachedFiles { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<BuyingList> BuyingLists { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<BuyingListItem> BuyingListItems { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<DeliveryPoint> DeliveryPoints { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<OrderCategory> OrderCategories { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<OrderValueLimit> OrderValueLimits { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<QtyPending> QtyPendings { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<ReceivedItem> ReceivedItems { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<tempVendor> tempVendors { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<UserFavouriteVendor> UserFavouriteVendors { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Vendor> Vendors { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<BuyingList>()
            .Property(e => e.TotalPrice)
            .HasPrecision(19, 4);

        modelBuilder.Entity<BuyingList>()
            .HasMany(e => e.BuyingListItems)
            .WithRequired(e => e.BuyingList)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<BuyingListItem>()
            .Property(e => e.Total)
            .HasPrecision(19, 4);

        modelBuilder.Entity<DeliveryPoint>()
            .HasMany(e => e.Orders)
            .WithRequired(e => e.DeliveryPoint)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Item>()
            .Property(e => e.UnitPrice)
            .HasPrecision(19, 4);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Item>()
            .HasMany(e => e.BuyingListItems)
            .WithRequired(e => e.Item)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Item>()
            .HasMany(e => e.OrderItems)
            .WithRequired(e => e.Item)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Item>()
            .HasMany(e => e.QtyPendings)
            .WithRequired(e => e.Item)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Item>()
            .HasMany(e => e.ReceivedItems)
            .WithRequired(e => e.Item)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
            .Property(e => e.Value)
            .HasPrecision(19, 4);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
            .Property(e => e.DeliveryCost)
            .HasPrecision(19, 4);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
            .HasMany(e => e.AttachedFiles)
            .WithRequired(e => e.Order)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
            .HasMany(e => e.OrderItems)
            .WithRequired(e => e.Order)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.OrderId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
            .HasMany(e => e.QtyPendings)
            .WithRequired(e => e.Order)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
            .HasMany(e => e.ReceivedItems)
            .WithRequired(e => e.Order)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<OrderCategory>()
            .HasMany(e => e.BuyingLists)
            .WithRequired(e => e.OrderCategory)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.CategoryId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<OrderItem>()
            .Property(e => e.TotalPrice)
            .HasPrecision(19, 4);

        modelBuilder.Entity<OrderItem>()
            .HasMany(e => e.Orders)
            .WithOptional(e => e.OrderItem)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.OrderItemsId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<OrderValueLimit>()
            .Property(e => e.ValueLimit)
            .HasPrecision(19, 4);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Vendor>()
            .HasMany(e => e.BuyingLists)
            .WithRequired(e => e.Vendor)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.VendorId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Vendor>()
            .HasMany(e => e.Items)
            .WithRequired(e => e.Vendor)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.VendorID)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Vendor>()
            .HasMany(e => e.Orders)
            .WithRequired(e => e.Vendor)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.VendorID)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Vendor>()
            .HasMany(e => e.UserFavouriteVendors)
            .WithRequired(e => e.Vendor)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.VendorId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }


    public async Task<IQueryable<TEntity>> Load<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
    {
        var set = await Task.FromResult(Set<TEntity>());

        return set;
    }

    public async Task Create<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : class
    {
        if (Entry(entity).State == EntityState.Detached)
            Set<TEntity>().Add(entity);
        await this.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    public async Task Update<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : class
    {
        if (Entry(entity).State == EntityState.Detached)
            Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
        await this.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    public async Task Delete<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : class
    {
        if (Entry(entity).State == EntityState.Detached)
            Set<TEntity>().Remove(entity);
        await this.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    public async Task<IQueryable<TEntity>> Query<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
    {
        return await Task.FromResult(Set<TEntity>().AsNoTracking()); // detach results from context
    }
}
```

Store:

```
    public class OrderStore<TOrder>
{
    IWritePurchasingEntities _iWrite;

    public OrderStore(IWritePurchasingEntities iWrite)
    {
        _iWrite = iWrite;
    }
    public async Task<List<OrderDTO>> GetAll()
    {
        var orders = await _iWrite.Load<Order>();
        return orders.ToList().ToDto();
    }
    public async Task<List<OrderDTO>> GetAll(string userId)
    {
        var orders = await _iWrite.Query<Order>();
        return orders.Where(p => p.UserId == userId).ToList().ToDto();
    }
    public async Task<OrderDTO> GetOne(int id)
    {
        var order = await _iWrite.Query<Order>();
        return order.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id).ToDto();
    }
    public void Create(OrderDTO order)
    {
        _iWrite.Create<Order>(order.FromDto());
    }
    public void Update(OrderDTO order)
    {
        _iWrite.Update<Order>(order.FromDto());
    }
    public void Delete(int orderId)
    {
        var order = _iWrite.Query<Order>().Result.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == orderId);
        _iWrite.Delete<Order>(order);
    }
}
```

Manager:

```
    public class OrderManager : OrderStore<Order>, IOrderManager
{
    IWritePurchasingEntities _iWrite;

    Random random = new Random();

    public OrderManager(IWritePurchasingEntities iWrite)
        :base(iWrite)
    {
        _iWrite = iWrite;
    }

    public async Task ReceivedItemsOnOrder(ReceivedItemDTO receivedDto, QtyPendingDTO pendingDto)
    {
        var order = await GetOne(receivedDto.OrderId);
        if (order.ReceivedItems == null)
        {
            order.ReceivedItems = new List<ReceivedItemDTO>();
        }
        if (order.QtyPendings == null)
        {
            order.QtyPendings = new List<QtyPendingDTO>();
        }
        if (order.QtyPendings.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ItemId == receivedDto.ItemId) == null)
        {
            pendingDto.Id = random.Next(1000000, 9999999);
            pendingDto.OrderId = receivedDto.OrderId;
            pendingDto.ItemId = receivedDto.ItemId;
            pendingDto.QtyOrdered = order.OrderItems.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ItemID == receivedDto.ItemId).Qty;
            pendingDto.QtyPending1 = (int)(pendingDto.QtyOrdered - receivedDto.QtyReceived);
            order.QtyPendings.Add(pendingDto);
        }
        else
        {

            order.QtyPendings.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ItemId == receivedDto.ItemId).QtyPending1 -= (int)receivedDto.QtyReceived;
        }
        receivedDto.Id = random.Next(1000000, 9999999);
        order.ReceivedItems.Add(receivedDto);
        Update(order);
    }

    public async Task<int> GetOrderId()
    {
        var orders = await _iWrite.Query<Order>();
        int orderId;
        if (orders == null || orders.ToList().Count == 0)
            orderId = 100000;
        else
            orderId = orders.OrderBy(q => q.Id).Select(p => p.Id).Last() + 1;
        return orderId;
    }
```

Service:

```
    public class OrderService : IOrderService
{
    IOrderManager _orderManager;

    public OrderService(IOrderManager orderManager)
    {
        _orderManager = orderManager;
    }

    public async Task<List<OrderDTO>> GetAll()
    {
        return await _orderManager.GetAll();
    }

    public async Task<List<OrderDTO>> GetAll(string userId)
    {
        return await _orderManager.GetAll(userId);
    }

    public async Task<OrderDTO> GetOne(int id)
    {
        return await _orderManager.GetOne(id);
    }

    public void Create(OrderDTO order)
    {
        _orderManager.Create(order);
    }

    public void Update(OrderDTO order)
    {
        _orderManager.Update(order);
    }
    public void Delete(int orderId)
    {
        _orderManager.Delete(orderId);
    }
    public async Task<int> GetOrderId()
    {
        var orderId = await _orderManager.GetOrderId();
        return orderId;
    }
    public async Task ReceivedItemsOnOrder(ReceivedItemDTO received, QtyPendingDTO pending)
    {
        await _orderManager.ReceivedItemsOnOrder(received, pending);
    }
}
```

And finally Controller (this is a bit long, 1500 lines, but I am only copying the actions used on the index page where i load the table):

```
    public class OrderController : Controller
{
    IOrderService _orderService;
    IVendorService _vendorService;
    IItemService _itemService;
    IDeliveryPointService _deliveryPointService;
    IOrderCategoryService _orderCategoryService;
    IOrderValueLimitService _orderValueLimitService;
    IBuyingListService _buyingListService;
    NotificationService _notificationService;
    IAttachedFilesService _attachedFileServices;

    protected ApplicationDbContext ApplicationDbContext { get; set; }
    protected UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager { get; set; }


    public OrderController(IOrderService orderService,
                            IVendorService vendorService,
                            IItemService itemService,
                            IDeliveryPointService deliveryPointService,
                            IOrderCategoryService orderCategoryService,
                            IOrderValueLimitService orderValueLimitService,
                            IBuyingListService buyingListService,
                            IWriteNotifications iWrite,
                            IAttachedFilesService attachedFileServices)
    {
        _orderService = orderService;
        _vendorService = vendorService;
        _itemService = itemService;
        _deliveryPointService = deliveryPointService;
        _orderCategoryService = orderCategoryService;
        _orderValueLimitService = orderValueLimitService;
        _buyingListService = buyingListService;
        _notificationService = new NotificationService(iWrite);
        _attachedFileServices = attachedFileServices;
        ApplicationDbContext _ctx = new ApplicationDbContext();
        this.ApplicationDbContext = new ApplicationDbContext();
        this.UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(this.ApplicationDbContext));
    }

    //Getting the models
    OrderModel om = new OrderModel();

    //i need this for generating id's.
    Random random = new Random();

    //This is the main view for the index page, it is empty because i will use partial views from child actions to populate it with content.
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    //Get a list of orders and sort them by the specified property
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult> List(string sortOrder)
    {
        //set up the appropriate services for order listing
        om.FavouriteVendors = await _vendorService.GetFavourites(User.Identity.GetUserId());
        List<OrderDTO> orders;
        //Get the appropriate order list depending on the user access
        if (User.Identity.HasEdit("Authoriser"))
        {
            orders = await _orderService.GetAll();
        }
        else
        {
            orders = await _orderService.GetAll(User.Identity.GetUserId());
        }

        //Get a list of users with pending orders
        om.Users = new List<ApplicationUser>();
        var userIds = new List<string>();
        foreach (var order in orders)
            if (userIds.Contains(order.UserId) == false)
                userIds.Add(order.UserId);
        foreach (var id in userIds)
            om.Users.Add(UserManager.Users.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id));

        //Get a list of vendors with pending orders
        var orderVendors = new List<VendorDTO>();
        var orderVendorsId = _orderService.GetAll().Result.Select(p => p.VendorID).ToList();
        foreach (var vendorId in orderVendorsId)
        {

            var vendor = await _vendorService.GetOne(vendorId);
            if (orderVendors.Select(p => p.Vendor1).Contains(vendor.Vendor1) == false)
                orderVendors.Add(vendor);
        }

        //Sort the orderList
        ViewBag.CreatedByParam = sortOrder == "by" ? "by_desc" : "by";
        ViewBag.CreatedOnParam = sortOrder == "on" ? "on_desc" : "on";
        ViewBag.VendorParam = sortOrder == "vendor" ? "vendor_desc" : "vendor";
        ViewBag.POParam = sortOrder == "po" ? "po_desc" : "po";
        switch (sortOrder)
        {
            case "by":
                om.Orders = orders.OrderBy(q => om.Users.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == q.UserId).UserName).ToList();
                break;
            case "by_desc":
                om.Orders = orders.OrderByDescending(q => om.Users.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == q.UserId).UserName).ToList();
                break;
            case "on":
                om.Orders = orders.OrderBy(p => p.OrderDate).ToList();
                break;
            case "on_desc":
                om.Orders = orders.OrderByDescending(p => p.OrderDate).ToList();
                break;
            case "vendor":
                om.Orders = orders.OrderBy(p => orderVendors.FirstOrDefault(q => q.Vendor1 == p.VendorID).VendorName).ToList();
                break;
            case "vendor_desc":
                om.Orders = orders.OrderByDescending(p => orderVendors.FirstOrDefault(q => q.Vendor1 == p.VendorID).VendorName).ToList();
                break;
            case "po":
                om.Orders = orders.OrderBy(p => p.Id).ToList();
                break;
            case "po_desc":
                om.Orders = orders.OrderByDescending(p => p.Id).ToList();
                break;
            default:
                om.Orders = orders.OrderByDescending(p => p.OrderDate).ToList();
                break;
        }

        //Set up the dropdown list of vendors which will be used to filter the list.
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> orderVendorsList = orderVendors.Select(b => new SelectListItem { Value = b.Vendor1, Text = b.VendorName }).OrderBy(q => q.Text);
        ViewBag.OrderVendors = orderVendorsList;

        return PartialView(om);
    }

    //Applying the filters
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult> FilterList(string FilterByVendor, bool IsAuthorised, bool GoodsReceived, bool PassedForPayment)
    {
        //set up the appropriate services for order listing
        om.FavouriteVendors = await _vendorService.GetFavourites(User.Identity.GetUserId());
        om.Users = UserManager.Users.ToList();


        //Get the appropriate order list depending on the user access
        var orders = new List<OrderDTO>();
        if (User.Identity.HasEdit("Authoriser"))
        {
            om.Orders = await _orderService.GetAll();
        }
        else
        {
            om.Orders = await _orderService.GetAll(User.Identity.GetUserId());
        }

        //Apply the filters

        if (FilterByVendor != null && FilterByVendor != "")
            om.Orders = om.Orders.Where(p => p.VendorID == FilterByVendor).ToList();
        if (FilterByVendor == "")
            om.Orders = om.Orders.ToList();
        if (IsAuthorised)
            om.Orders = om.Orders.Where(p => p.IsAuthorized == IsAuthorised).ToList();
        if (GoodsReceived)
            om.Orders = om.Orders.Where(p => p.GoodsReceived == GoodsReceived).ToList();
        if (PassedForPayment)
            om.Orders = om.Orders.Where(p => p.PassedForPayment == PassedForPayment).ToList();

        return PartialView(om);
    }
```

}

and model for the order page controller

```
    public class OrderModel
{
    public ICollection<OrderDTO> Orders { get; set; }
    public ICollection<VendorDTO> Vendors { get; set; }
    public ICollection<VendorDTO> FavouriteVendors { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ItemDTO> Items { get; set; }
    public ICollection<OrderItemsDTO> ItemsList { get; set; }
    public ICollection<DeliveryPointDTO> DeliveryPoints { get; set; }
    public ICollection<OrderCategoryDTO> OrderCategories { get; set; }
    public ICollection<OrderItemsDTO> OrderItems { get; set; }
    public ICollection<HttpPostedFileBase> AttachedFiles { get; set; }
    public ICollection<AttachedFilesDTO> Files { get; set; }
    public ICollection<IdentityRole> Roles { get; set; }
    public ICollection<BuyingListDTO> BuyingLists { get; set; }
    public ICollection<BuyingListItemDTO> BuyingListItems { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public VendorDTO Vendor { get; set; }
    public VendorDTO FavouriteVendor { get; set; }
    public DeliveryPointDTO DeliveryPoint { get; set; }
    public OrderCategoryDTO OrderCategory { get; set; }
    public OrderDTO Order { get; set; }
    public OrderValueLimitDTO Limit {get; set;}
    public AttachedFilesDTO File { get; set; }
    public BuyingListDTO BuyingList { get; set; }
    public BuyingListItemDTO BuyingListItem { get; set; }
    public ItemDTO Item { get; set; }
}
```

and while debugging I also get this:
[image]

my question is: Is this behaviour right? or did I do something wrong? Almost every method I've build is async, My code metrics results look good for now (the project isn't very big yet). I need to make things work faster. If right now I'm loading that page in 30 seconds, with less than 100 rows of data, I don't wanna know what it's gonna be like with 1000 or 10.000 rows, or more...

P.S., my diagnostic tools also look good i guess, around 3-400 mb memory at most and processor usually under 25 percent but with rare spikes up to 75, but like i said, they're only spikes, it's not staying there.

Comment: pls clarify: 
Does it take around 30 sec for EVERY request or just the first one?
Where is the "hang"? in the query execution (eg: `.ToList`) or somewhere else?

Comment: It takes that time for every request, not just the first one, the first one takes about 10 seconds longer but I understand why. The hang is in my store class.

Comment: Debug your code and then check where it is taking time. If it is just a query which is taking time than you will have to include the models too in the question.

Comment: @Spluf pls be more specific. Where in the Store class? Every operation? have you checked the database itself (maybe its clogged-up)? Have you checked the outgoing calls to the database?

Comment: Leonardo, It's all there in my question (including my store class). Every method that should return a list has a `ToList()`. Also, the Load method that is being called returns the `Set<TEntity>()`. I also stated that I checked my database and the calls are being broke down to each row, so in stead of getting that set, it's doing one call for each row in that table.

Comment: @Spluf - i would suggest you to take a look on this video.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GmyVMSf4DtE&feature=youtu.be

Comment: @Shoeb siddique thanks a lot, this is great,  can't wait to get back to the office and try this. And a happy and productive new year as well :)

Comment: This app needs to be profiled. I've created an EF profiler which lets you to track all of the DB calls and possible flaws: https://github.com/VahidN/DNTProfiler

Comment: cool VahidN, I'll definitely use this. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, since nobody else took credit for this, here's the thing. That page was loading in 30 seconds? now it loads in around 30ms. So  0.03 seconds. The main problem of that behaviour was using generic interfaces. It looks cool, it's easy to maintain and all that, but the drawbacks are HUGE in specially on the SQL server. So, in stead of using that generic (can't say that I completely removed it, still using it in some places, for now at least) I have built a repository layer(since I don't want my domain classes to depend on anything concrete) and wrote new, optimised queries for every object i have. It's amazing how much of a difference is between `var y = context.Objects.ToList()` and `var y = context.Objects.Select(p => new { x = p.name}).ToList()`, even if the object has just that one property. Projection saved the day for me. Thanks everyone for the comments and in specially @shoeb siddique for the video ( http://youtube.com/watch?v=GmyVMSf4DtE&feature=youtu.be ), it was exactly what I needed, and also VahidN for his profiler ( http://github.com/VahidN/DNTProfiler ).

Hope this helps someone else. So the short answer is: Projection and optimised queries in stead of generics.